# Completely incorrect TypeScript errors: Property x does not exist on type y

Tags: reactjs, typescript, types, react-typescript

My team and I are experiencing some obviously incorrect TypeScript errors in a React project.

Here's some JSX:

```
                    <PatchField
                        name="name"
                        render={({ value, setValue }) => (
                            <Input
                                placeholder="Enter a name"
                                value={(value ?? "").toString()}
                                onChange={getHandleTextValueChange(setValue)}
                                maxLength={TITLE_FIELD_MAX_LENGTH}
                                showInputLength={false}
                                variant="ghost"
                                size="large"
                            />
                        )}
                    />
```

There is an error on the `name="name"` line:

```
S2322: Type
    {
        name: string;
        render: ({ value, setValue }: {
            value: any;
            setValue: any;
        }) => Element;
    }
is not assignable to type IntrinsicAttributes
Property name does not exist on type IntrinsicAttributes
```

Emphasis on "property `name` does not exist on type `IntrinsicAttributes`."

The problem is that the props of `PatchField` (`ComponentProps<typeof PatchField>`) *does* have a `name` field.

In WebStorm, I can easily go to the definition of `name` (`Ctrl+B` or `Ctrl+LClick` or `RClick -> Go To -> Type Declaration`) and see this:

```
interface PatchFieldProps {
    name: string;
    render: (args: RenderArgs) => ReactNode;
}
```

In fact, when I hover over the `name` prop in WebStorm, I see this:

[image]

The interface **clearly** includes `name`. Why could I (and my team) be getting this error? Why does TypeScript think that the prop type of `PatchField` is `IntrinsicAttributes`? I can plainly see that the declared type of the props of `PatchField` is indeed **not** `IntrinsicAttributes`.

We are all on recent versions of TypeScript. I am personally on v4.9.5.

Note that this is **not a WebStorm-specific problem** as I get type errors on this when running `tsc --noEmit`.

EDIT:

The code that describes `PatchField`:

```
import { memo, ReactNode, useMemo } from "react"
import { useField, useFormikContext } from "formik"
import { FieldValue } from "../../typings.ts"

interface PatchFieldProps {
    name: string
    render: (args: RenderArgs) => ReactNode
}

export const PatchField = memo((props: PatchFieldProps) => {
    const { name, render } = props
    const { submitForm } = useFormikContext()
    const [fieldProps, _meta, helpers] = useField<FieldValue>(name)

    return useMemo(() => {
        const setValue = (value: FieldValue) => {
            void helpers.setValue(value, false)
        }
        return render({
            value: fieldProps.value,
            setValue,
            patchValue: () => {
                void submitForm()
            },
        })
    }, [submitForm, helpers, fieldProps.value, render])
})
```

Comment: The fact that it's talking about `IntrinsicAttributes` suggests that you forgot to type the actual `PatchField` component and as far as TS can tell, your component properties are just the universal React component properties. So: can you show the code that defines `PatchField`?

Comment: Thanks @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans. I definitely did not forget to type `PatchField`. All components are subject to strict mode (in both TypeScript and code review, haha). The component is definitely typed with `PatchFieldProps`, which is described in the original question.

Comment: I don't actually see a type import for `PatchFieldProps` anywhere in that `PatchField` definition?

Comment: Sorry, I seem to have removed it from the code snippet because I had already shown it, but I see it might be confusing. The interface is declared directly above `PatchField`. Edited.

Comment: Cheers - now, this might sound annoying but: now you get to reduce that to [mcve] form. Not even so much "for your post", but because you're not showing something that can be reduce: remove the memoization and just return an empty div: does TS still flag an error? Remove the field/formik code. Does TS still flag an error? And so on until TS _stops_ reporting an error or you've arrived at what is basically an empty component with an app that _only_ loads the one instance of that component with a `name` property, and TS is still reporting the wrong thing.

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out in the comments, this can be reduced. I have reduced it to this:

```
import { ReactNode } from "react"
import { FieldValue } from "../../typings.ts"

interface RenderArgs {
    value: FieldValue
    setValue: (value: FieldValue) => void
    patchValue: () => void
}

interface PatchFieldProps {
    name: string
    render: (args: RenderArgs) => ReactNode
}

export const PatchField = (props: PatchFieldProps) => {
    console.log("PatchField props:", props)
    return null
}

PatchField.displayName = "PatchField"
```

The error went away (after a minute or so of whichever processes are involved catching up). I gradually reconstructed the original component and found that returning the `ReactNode` returned by the `useMemo` hook caused the issue.

By wrapping the returned value in a fragment, the error disappears:

```
export const PatchField = memo((props: PatchFieldProps) => {
    const { name, render } = props
    const { submitForm } = useFormikContext()
    const [fieldProps, _meta, helpers] = useField<FieldValue>(name)

    const ret: ReactNode = useMemo(() => {
        const setValue = (value: FieldValue) => {
            void helpers.setValue(value, false)
        }
        return render({
            value: fieldProps.value,
            setValue,
            patchValue: () => {
                void submitForm()
            },
        })
    }, [submitForm, helpers, fieldProps.value, render])

    return <>{ret}</>
})
```

I find this very odd, and I have no explanation as to why returning a `ReactNode` directly would cause the prop not to be recognized, but it works.